# OpenMP threads doing repeated work/desynchronization

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm trying to parallelize a recursive function (which solves the Knight's Tour problem by basically trying every possible path/backtracking) using OpenMP. OpenMP tasks should do the job in most cases, but the threads are ocasionally doing repeated work/desynchronizing which causes the program to hang.
This is the function call:

```
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(8)
    {
      #pragma omp single
      {
        if(!findtour(*this, 0)) {
          cout << "No solutions found\n";
        }
      }
    }
```

And this is the function itself:

```
bool tour::findtour(tour& T, int imove) {
  if(imove == (size*size - 1)) return true;
  // make a move
  int cx = T.sx;
  int cy = T.sy;
  int cs = T.size;
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
    int tcx = cx + movimento[i][0];
    int tcy = cy + movimento[i][1];
    // Is this a valid move?
    // Has this place been visited yet
    if ((tcx >= 0) &&  (tcy >= 0)  &&  (tcx < cs) &&  (tcy < cs) && (T.board[tcx][tcy] == -1)) {
      tour temp(T);
      temp.board[tcx][tcy] = imove+1;
      temp.sx = tcx;
      temp.sy = tcy;
      #pragma omp task firstprivate(T, imove, temp)
      {
        if(findtour(temp, imove+1)) {
          cout << temp << endl;
          exit(1);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  #pragma omp taskwait
  return false;
}
```

I can't tell what exactly is causing the issue as I have tried changing many of the shared/private variables so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 1. Why do you pass in a `Tour` object as parameter, when `findtour` is a method of the `Tour` class? That looks like bad design. 2. Using `exit` to end the search is quite inelegant. There are better ways to abort the search. 3. the `firstprivate` clause is not needed because that's the default for a task.

Comment: My guess is that the copy constructor of `tour` is not properly implemented, but it is not possible to tell without a [mre].